# Prop value passed to child does have most updated value of the parent's state - React

Tags: reactjs

I am using React, and I am passing the value of `mode` to the child like so:

```
<Child mode={this.state.mode}/>
```

and I can successfully obtain the `mode` value from the parent in my child class.

Next, I wanted to be able to update `mode` in the parent class from the child class, so I passed `updateModeState` to the child and created the function to do so:

```
<Child updateModeState={this.updateModeState} eyemode={this.state.eyemode}/>
```

So this is what I have in my parent class I have this:

```
class Parent extends BaseComponent {

    state = {
        mode: 'mode 1',
    }

    updateModeState(mode) {
        this.setState({
            mode: mode
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <Child updateModeState={this.updateModeState} eyemode={this.state.eyemode}/>
    }

}
```

Now, in Child, I have an onClick method that should toggle the state:

```
class Child extends BaseComponent {
    onClick() {
        if (this.props.mode == 'mode 1') {
            this.props.updateModeState('mode 2');
            console.log(this.props.mode);
            // Still logs "mode 1"
        } else {
            this.props.updateModeState('mode 1');
            console.log(this.props.mode);
            // Still logs "mode 2"
        }            
    }
}
```

As seen in the comments in the code. I am updating the state, but the props do not get updated. I thought that the props were always in sync with the state, so why are the props not updating right after I set the state?

I have also looked into Redux, as well as creating another method in the Parent class to return the value of state.

Is the option I'm pursuing viable? Or are the other 2 I mentioned better practice?

Comment: Did you bind the class method which you sent to child as prop? Because it will use setState which is function of parent component and the `this` will need to know which scope it in.

Answer (score 0):

The props of a component are set when mounting the component. Changing them after mounting will not update them inside the mounted component.

You have a few possible ways to solve this. First take a look at the `componentWillReceiveProps` and `getDerivedStateFromProps` hooks. This article might help understand them: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Basically you want to save the prop of a parent in the childs state and work with that. When the parent passes new props to the child you want to detect this and update the childs state. Those hooks will help you do this.

Answer (score 0):

**General information:** I don't recommended you to send directly all state object or which will be change as object. React uses **shallow comparison** to know which props are changed. And it doesn't check each part of the object. The shallow comparison, will check the reference of the object. You could send each part of state as you need. And it going to be have updated.

You can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` in the **class** components. It's static
 life cycle method of React. But it will be triggered each props change. And still you should check the your new needed props in the life cycle method to don't re-render unnecessarily.

As the snippet:

```
class Child extends BaseComponent
{
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(newProps, currentState)
  {
    if (newProps.some !== currentState.some)
    {
      return ({ some: newProps.some }); // it will make change the state with new prop value
    }

    console.log(newProps); // also you can listen the changes for simple debugging

    return null; // if nothing changed
  }

....
}
```

**Official Documentation:** (not enough to understand but still) https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

In the other hand, you can set a key to your child component something like this `<Child key={this.state.eyemode} ....`. But you should be careful for performance reasons when you use keys. If the key going to change each render unnecessarily then it's not good solution in the situation.

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys